# org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize java.io.EOFException at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully

Tags: hibernate, serialization, eofexception

I want to query all instance of the entity `Translation`, which has reference to the entity `Text`. But, despite marking the `Entity` class with `Serializable`, hibernate complains. Why is that?

FYI I added `Serializable` to all of my `Entity` classes. The backing bean is @RequestScoped and annotated with @Named (CDI).

```
package com.doe.webapp.model.general.i18n;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import com.doe.webapp.model.RootEntity;

@Entity
public class Translation extends RootEntity  implements Serializable {

    public Translation(){
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * a text may have multiple translations.
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "textId")
    private Text textUnit;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="localeId")
    private Locale locale;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String translation;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Text getTextUnit() {
        return textUnit;
    }

    public void setTextUnit(Text textUnit) {
        this.textUnit = textUnit;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

}
```

I query this entity like this:

```
public List<Translation> getTranslations(Long id) {
        List<Translation> translations = new LinkedList<Translation>();
        CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Translation> criteriaQuery = critBuilder.createQuery(Translation.class);
        Root<Translation> translation = criteriaQuery.from(Translation.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(translation);              
        criteriaQuery.where(critBuilder.equal(translation.get(Translation_.id), id));

        TypedQuery<Translation> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        translations = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return translations;
    }
```

And the error on invocation of this method is:

```
    Caused by: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.doe.webapp.repository.general.i18n.TextRepository$$$view8.getTranslations(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:401) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:99) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.doe.webapp.repository.general.i18n.TextRepository$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getTranslations(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at com.doe.webapp.controller.admin.TextController.getTranslations(TextController.java:121) [classes:]
    at com.doe.webapp.controller.admin.TextController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getTranslations(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at com.doe.webapp.repository.general.i18n.TextRepository.getTranslations(TextRepository.java:106) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 122 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:262) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:324) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:107) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:255) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 159 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 205 more
```

Does anybody have a clue why hibernate still complains?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: The EOFException is wiered...

Comment: I simply had a wrong relationship defined between Locale and Translation.@ManyToOne
        private Text textUnit;

        @ManyToOne
        private Locale locale;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Divide&Conquered by simply cutting each relationship and retried. It turned out to be a wrong relationship type definition for Locale. I removed the wrongly declared @JoinColumn defintions and changed it to a m-to-1 relationship.

```
@ManyToOne
private Locale locale;
```

Nothing more to do than that. I hope this helps another stackoverflower.